# Ubuntu 18.04. Acces to samba share via gui is slow but fast in terminal

Tags: networking, mount, nautilus, samba

On an Ubuntu 18.04 system, I have a samba share mounted by root with

```
mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/share /mnt/T -o credentials=/home/user/.credentials.txt,uid=user,gid=user,iocharset=utf8
```

Doing a copy via command line

```
cp /mnt/T/file.name .
```

is instantaneous but doing the same via nautilus or thunar takes over 20 seconds.

What could be causing this?